# wsdl array of objects

Tags: arrays, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I wrote wsdl file, then modified skeleton and tried to test. Something wrong with array of songs objects.

```
     <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfSongs">
       <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="item" type="tns:song"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="song">
      <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="artist" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="album" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="duration" type="xsd:int"/>
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

When I'm testing my service on netbeans I get unknown exception. Maybe I defined wrong complexType? I've created ArrayOfStrings, everything works fine, so what is wrong with ArrayOfSongs. Any information of creating arrays of objects would be helpful.

This service bind on SOAP, I used axis2, ant, tomcat server.

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to add more of the WSDL.  What style are you using? wrapped document/literal, rpc/literal, rpc/encoded? Does the exception occur when you start the service, or is it when you try to access the service? If you're using axis2, then there's probably an exception report being generated to the logs. Perhaps supply that as well.